# Como saber qual versão do navegador dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-cordova

Estou fazendo um projeto em  CORDOVA utilizando basicamente HTML, CSS, JS. Porém em alguns celulares a imagem de alguns ícones estão ficando do tamanho natural delas e em outros não, tenho utilizado basicamente `vh` para definir o tamanho das imagens. Para testar isto estou querendo verifica qual a versão do navegador está aberto, para verificar se existe portabilidade ou não.

Teria algum comando em javascript/jquery que faria isto ?

Comment: Fala Renan, caso queria existe um plugin jquery para isso https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin a vantagem dele é que ele tem a unificação de vários padrões de detecçao de browsers desde mobile em N SOs diferentes retornando a informação mais precisa possível.

Comment: http://www.whatbrowser.org/intl/pt-BR/
Muuuuito fácil...
Copia e cola o código que o gugãl criou.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em javascript é bem simples:

```
alert(navigator.appVersion);
```

Answer (score 7):

Você pode detectar qual navegador está sendo utilizado pelo usuário da seguinte forma:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9atsffau/)

```
    // Opera 8.0+
var opera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Firefox 1.0+
var firefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var safari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // Internet Explorer 6-11
var ie = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    // Edge 20+
var iedge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    // Chrome 1+
var chrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    // Blink engine detection
var blink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
```

Para detectar qual o navegador e sua respectiva versão, você pode utilizar a seguinte função, onde será retornado um objeto com o nome do navegador, sua versão e outras informações do navegador: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spt2cw0c/)

```
function get_browser(){
    var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []; 
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; 
        return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1]||'')};
        }   
    if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
        tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if(tem!=null)   {return {name:'Opera', version:tem[1]};}
        }   
    M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
    return {
      name: M[0],
      version: M[1]
    };
 }
```