# Compatibilidade do navegador com o javascript

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Existe alguma ferramenta ou método de reconhecer qual navegador o usuário esta utilizando e se este é compatível com a versão do JS e do JQuery que existe no meu sistema ?

A ideia é caso não seja compatível, alertar o usuário e bloquear o sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A duvida se baseava em saber se o navegador do cliente era compatível com os recursos do javascript que o sistema utilizava.
Para solucionar o problema foi utilizado a biblioteca [`Modernizr`](https://modernizr.com/docs/)
A mesma da suporte para verificar os recursos que o navegador suporta.

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar qual o navegador e sua respectiva versão, você pode utilizar a seguinte função, onde será retornado um objeto com o nome do navegador, sua versão e outras informações do navegador:

```js
    // Opera 8.0+
var opera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Firefox 1.0+
var firefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var safari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // Internet Explorer 6-11
var ie = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    // Edge 20+
var iedge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    // Chrome 1+
var chrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    // Blink engine detection
var blink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
```

Para detectar qual o navegador e sua respectiva versão, você pode utilizar a seguinte função, onde será retornado um objeto com o nome do navegador, sua versão e outras informações do navegador:

```js
function get_browser(){
    var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []; 
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; 
        return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1]||'')};
        }   
    if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
        tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if(tem!=null)   {return {name:'Opera', version:tem[1]};}
        }   
    M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
    return {
      name: M[0],
      version: M[1]
    };
 }
```

Fonte: [Como saber qual versão do navegador dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138845/como-saber-qual-vers%C3%A3o-do-navegador-dinamicamente)

Answer (score 0):

Usar `J-query` já é uma estratégia para que o código `javascript` rode em vários navegadores até mesmo nos antigos, mas é claro que existe algumas exceções como quando o navegador é pré histórico ou quando o usuário desativa o `javascript`, uma alternativa para esses casos é usar o `no-script`, exemplo...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Desculpe! esse navegador não suporta javascript</noscript>

<p>Esse navegador suporta javascript</p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Referência** [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)