# Como bloquear o IE de abrir o website?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Foi-me pedido que bloqueasse o acesso a um determinado website, sempre que o mesmo fosse realizado pelo Internet Explorer (independentemente da versão).

Tenho feito algumas pesquisas e testes e não tenho conseguido obter sucesso.

Agradeço a vossa ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi direto, vc quer que se o cara estiver no IE e tentar entrar em um site aparece um Alert por exemplo? Ou que para quem acessar do IE o site aparece um uma mensagem ou com algum outro tipo de conteúdo? Poderia dar mais detalhes

Comment: @hugocsl, sim... quero que quando o usuário acesse através do IE, seja mostrada uma div, por exemplo, com o blockUI. Mas o problema não é mostrar a div, é mesmo saber quando é que o usuário está a acessar pelo IE...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como saber qual versão do navegador dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138845/como-saber-qual-vers%c3%a3o-do-navegador-dinamicamente)

Comment: @LipESprY, não me parece que é a mesma dúvida...

Comment: @FilipeMartins propus a duplicata porque a resposta lá aborda o suficiente pra responder sua pergunta. Mas tá valendo! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    const isInternetExplorer = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1

    if (isInternetExplorer) {
        // sua ação (redirecionar usuario para outra pagina, etc.)
    }
</script>
```